# Drawing on canvas with iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, html

I found this http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1867-Drawing-On-The-iPhone-Canvas-With-jQuery-And-ColdFusion.htm example on how to draw on a canvas with the iPhone (which works) but it doesn't work on my iPad. When I try to draw something all I can do is to make straight lines from the same starting point. Also it doesn't disable the scroll function like on the iPhone so when I draw it sometimes scroll as well which of course I don't wont.

Is there any other example out there that explains how to make this work on the iPad as well or do you know how to customize the code?

Thanks in advance.

Edit, change it to isiPhone to isiPad solved it of course.

Answer (score 4):

I've written something similar for doing basic drawing on the ipad. You can find the source code at the top of the blog post: http://tenderlovingcode.com/blog/web-apps/html5-canvas-drawing-on-ipad . Hope it helps!